# Can't validate the first value from lightning:InputField using as picklist

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, lightning-inputfield

Resume of scenario: Whether a user does not select any value from the picklist the field should throw an error message.

```
<lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="raiseIssueForm"
                              recordTypeId="{!v.recordExample}"
                              objectApiName="Case"
                              recordId="{!v.valueExample}"
                              onload="{!c.onLoadIssue}"
                              onsubmit="{!c.onSubmitIssue}"
                              onsuccess="{!onSuccessfulRaiseIssueSubmission}"
                              onerror="{!c.onRaiseIssueSubmissionError}"
                              class="slds-card__body_inner">
    <div class="slds-form">
        <div class="slds-form-element slds-form-element_stacked slds-size_1-of-4">

            <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="issueType">{!$Label.c.example}</label>
            <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                <lightning:inputField aura:id="issueType"
                                      class="example__class"
                                      fieldName="Type"
                                      variant="label-hidden"
                                      required="true"
                                      value="{!v.selectedIssueType}"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</lightning:recordEditForm>
```

Piece of code from my helper, the picklist loads with --None-- as usual, and whether I press submit the alert doesn't show anything, although if I change the value I can see it. So my question: How does it possible validating if it's empty instead to loop through all values checking if it's different for example?

```js
var field = component.find("issueType").get("v.value");
     this.checkEmptyField(component, field);
      //just an example
     if(issueType != '--None--') {
         alert(issueType);
     }
```

Comment: have you considered using an 'onchange' event, and crosschecking the value ?

Comment: no, because I am trying to capture the first value without users change it (if they left not selected I mean)

Comment: so you are saying if "none" is already selected in "Type" picklist and then you click on submit it wont throw any error and will save your record?

Comment: Technically there's nothing selected, as my alert shows empty and I couldn't pick up the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I already had the value from the field itself, but no references (typeOf, instanceOf) using the exclamation mark (not) was possible validating.

```
if(!issueType) { code.. }
```